# Difference between DNF and CNF

Tags: propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I'm stuck on this particular question:

> Let $A$ be the following propositional formula $$(\lnot p \rightarrow q) \leftrightarrow\ (\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot r)$$ Find a propositional formula **$B$** in DNF that is logically equivalent to $A$

I don't understand about this DNF, can someone help please?

Comment: did you had a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form ?

Comment: Yes I have had a look
But I'm still unsure about the difference, because what if it had both $\lor$ and $\land$, or something like that?

Comment: the difference is that conjunction and disjunction have a different hierarchy (using brackets). according to  your question, you do not need the CNF, but only DNF, so maybe the title is not optimal.

Comment: There is a specific algorithm using a truth table to generate a DNF. Can you provide information about where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: **DNF** is a disjunction of conjunctive clauses, something like $(p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land r)$. Thus, you have to remove the $\to$ using the boolean equivalence : $(p \to q) \equiv (\lnot p \lor q)$ and then, if needed, apply *Distributivity*.

Answer (score 1):

We say that a formula is in disjunctive normal form if it is a disjunction of conjunctions of literals.

More formally:

> **Definition**: We say that a formula $\varphi$ is in disjunctive normal form if$$\varphi =\bigvee_{i \leq n}\bigwedge_{j \leq m} \varphi_{ij}$$
>   where $ϕ_{ij}$ is atomic or the negation of an atom (called a *literal*) and the notation for finite disjunction and conjuction means
>
> \begin{cases}
> \bigwedge_{i \leq 0} \varphi_i = \varphi_0\\
> \bigwedge_{i \leq n+1} \varphi_i = \bigwedge_{i \leq n} \varphi_i \wedge \varphi_{n+1}\\
> \end{cases}
>
> \begin{cases}
> \bigvee_{i \leq 0} \varphi_i = \varphi_0\\
> \bigvee_{i \leq n+1} \varphi_i = \bigvee_{i \leq n} \varphi_i \vee \varphi_{n+1}\\
> \end{cases}

Now recall that

1. $\alpha \rightarrow \beta \equiv \neg \alpha \lor \beta$
2. $\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta \equiv (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)\land(\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$.

Now why don't you try to apply those equivalences above? Distributivity may also be helpful to get rid of the outermost conjuction.